# How can I extract values from URL string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, greasemonkey, userscripts

I have a string like this:

```
http://x.com/xyz/2013/01/16/zz/040800.php
```

I want to get two strings from that, 
like this:

```
2013-01-16 <-- string 1
04:08:00 <-- string 2
```

How can I do that?

Comment: are your strings everytime of the same format?

Comment: yes. "x.com", "xyz" and "zz" are constant. others variable.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp and

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

Comment: @SunnyTAR if you click `help` on the right side of the comment box, you can see how to add `links` to comments

Comment: @bart s I am on my way. testing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the url is always of the same format, do this

```
var string = 'http://x.com/xyz/2013/01/16/zz/040800.php';

var parts = string.split('/');

var string1 = parts[4] +'-' +parts[5] +"-" +parts[6];
var string2 = parts[8][0]+parts[8][1] +":" +parts[8][2]+parts[8][3] +":" +parts[8][4]+parts[8][5];

alert(string1);
alert(string2);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/algorhythm/sZM4D/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use regulax expressions. Here is a sample solution:

```
var parts = (/.com\/[^\/]+\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/g).exec('http://x.com/xyz/2013/01/16/zz/040800.php'),
    result = parts[1] + '-' + parts[2] + '-' + parts[3]; //"2013-01-16"
```

This will work if your domain is `.com` and you have just one extra parameter before the date.

Let me explain you the regular expression:

```
 /          //starts the regular expression
 .com       //matches .com
   \/       //matches /
   [^\/]+   //matches anything except /
      \/    //matches a single /
      (\d+) //matches more digits (one or more)
      \/    //matches /
   (\d+)    //matches more digits (one or more)
  \/        //matches /
 (\d+)      //matches more digits (one or more)
/           //ends the regular expression
```

Here is how you can extract the whole data:

```
var parts = (/.com\/[^\/]+\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/[^\/]+\/(\d+)/g).exec('http://x.com/xyz/2013/01/16/zz/040800.php'),
    part2 = parts[4];

parts[1] + '-' + parts[2] + '-' + parts[3]; //"2013-01-16"
part2[0] + part2[1] + ':' + part2[2] + part2[3] + ':' + part2[4] + part2[5];
```

Comment: Just updated my answer and included information about that how you can extract the second value too :-)